# How to select data from database higher than exact number

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I need to select users from database, which score (column named is time) is higher than 10. How to do that? For now It selecting all users.

For now my code:

```
    $query = "SELECT userName,min(time) time FROM game group by userName order by time ASC LIMIT 15";
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

Comment: What exactly has to be higher than 10? The minimum time you are selecting?

Comment: your problem is very unclear the way it is stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do:

```
SELECT userName,min(time) time 
FROM game WHERE time > 10 
group by userName 
order by time ASC LIMIT 15;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `WHERE` clause  to filter your result

```
SELECT userName,min(time) time 
FROM game
WHERE  `time` >10
group by userName 
order by time ASC LIMIT 15
```

or if you want to filter on resultset of aggregate function you can use `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT userName,min(time) time 
FROM game
group by userName 
HAVING  min(time) >10
order by time ASC LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add WHERE clause, like:

```
    $query = "SELECT userName,min(time) time FROM game WHERE time>10 group by userName order by time ASC LIMIT 15";
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

Comment: missing a closing `}` on `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add `HAVING MIN(time) >10` to your query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT userName, MIN(time) time FROM game GROUP BY username HAVING MIN(time) >10 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 15";
```

Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT userName, MIN(time) time 
FROM game
GROUP BY userName 
HAVING MIN(time) >10
ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 15
```